# Multiple arrays filled with individual paragraphs from text doc

Tags: arrays, swift

OSX - Swift
So I am filling a 'Keywords.rtf file' that i have added to my Module with a bunch of keywords. Because i am a neat freak I'm trying to do this the tidiest way i can think of.

I would like to have multiple paragraphs in the text doc and each paragraph will have similar strings separated by commas.

example of textDoc

```
Hi, Hey, Hello

Monday, Tuesday, Today is Wednesday

Apple, I like Bananas, I eat Orange's
```

Is it possible to then in my viewController, store these paragraphs in arrays. such as

```
var greetings = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello"]
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday" ,"Wednesday"]
var fruits = ["Apple" , "I like Bananas" , "I eat Orange's"]
```

To take it a little further is there a way i can have a heading above my paragraphs in the text file so when I store them in the array i can just say something like : let greet[] = all strings separatedBy(",") that are in the paragraph following "Greetings".

The text doc would look something like

```
Greetings
    Hi, Hey, Hello
Days    
    Monday, Tuesday, Today is Wednesday
Fruits    
    Apple, I like Bananas, I eat Orange's
```

Let me know if I can be more specific
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a *plist* file instead.

In Xcode, create an empty plist with New File -> Resource:

[image]

Then populate the plist:

[image]

Finally, get the contents for usage in your app:

```
let plist = // the URL to the plist, usually you put it in your bundle
guard let content = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: plist) as? [String:[String]] else {
    fatalError() // or anything else to handle the missing plist
}
guard let days = content["days"] else { fatalError() }
print(days) // ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
print(days[0]) // "Monday"
```

---

Following your comment: `content` is just a dictionary now, so to get all values you can do this:

```
let allValues = content.flatMap { (key, value) in return value }
```

Short version:

```
let allValues = content.flatMap { $0.1 }  // ["Apple", "I like Bananas", "I eat Orange's", "Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks for putting the time into a clear answer, I'll give it a crack now.

Comment: Worked great! I just had to change `contentsOfUrl` to `contentsOfFile`. Also how can i draw all values in this plist into one array? Is this possible?

Comment: Nice! I've updated my answer to show how to get all values.